# Sollte man Artikel im Akkusativ auf eine Einkaufsliste schreiben?

Tags: accusative

Weil ich die Artikel kaufen will, sollen sie denn im Akkusativ geschrieben werden?

z.B.

1. Schwarzen Pfeffer
2. Gerösteten Knoblauch

oder im Nominativ?

1. Schwarzer Pfeffer
2. Gerösteter Knoblauch

Comment: Das ist eine reine Geschmacksfrage. Da sich der Einkaufszettel nur an dich selbst richtet, kannst du ihn so schreiben, wie du ihn später lesen willst. Die meisten Deutschen die ich kenne schreiben die Artikel so abgekürzt auf ihre Einkaufszettel, dass der Kasus ohnehin nicht erkennbar ist.

Comment: Danke für Ihre Antwort! Wie würden Sie „schwarzer Pfeffer“ auf Ihre Einkaufsliste schreiben?

Comment: Ich würde "Pfeffer" schreiben und mich erinnern, dass es schwarzer sein sollte ;) Ansonsten "schw. Pfeffer"

Comment: Wenn die Liste nur für mich selber ist, würde ich "Pfeffer sw" schreiben, falls jemand anderes sie lesen soll, "Pfeffer schwarz", wie es auch auf dem Etikett des zu kaufenden Artikels steht.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Auch wenn ich die Idee hinter der Frage sehr charmant finde, kenne ich persönlich niemanden, der Einkaufslisten im Akkusativ schreibt.

Da es sich um eine reine Liste von Gegenständen ohne grammatische Struktur handelt, sehe ich auch keinen guten Grund dafür, etwas anderes als die Grundform (Nominativ) zu benutzen.

Die Überlegung, dass es sich um Dinge handelt, die man kaufen möchte, liefert auch keine eindeutige Antwort. Wenn man sich als Überschrift "Bitte kaufen:" vorstellt, wäre der Akkusativ sinnvoll, aber wenn man sich "Einzukaufen:" vorstellt, ist wieder der Nominativ richtig. Man könnte sich auch die Überschrift "Es mangelt an:" vorstellen und dann alles im Dativ schreiben, oder an "Wir bedürfen:" denken und den Genitiv nutzen. ;-)

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Erklärung!

Comment: "Man kaufe ..." :)